# Android Secret code receiver stopped working?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have declared a broadcast receiver in my manifest file for secret code, like below... when I first tested it on various devices it was working properly on different Android versions, including Android 8, but now I see it stops to work on certain devices, especially with Android 8, it seems the broadcast is not triggering and when I type `*#*#1122#*#*` on the dialer, it doesn't send any intent..

```
 <receiver android:name=".SecretCodeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE"/>
            <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="1122"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: I don't think the receivers registered in manifest will work after the app gets closed.

Comment: the app is not closed. also in that link, you can see that this action is not affected by android 8 background limitations

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

Comment: Broadcast Receiver stop working when your app is forced closed. Maybe your OS is force stopping your app. Run and try your app on stock Android ROM(unmodified) like Pixel, Nexus etc..

Comment: I'm using Nexus 6P, the app is not closed or forced close by the system.
for example, I just clicked on the home button so the app is on the background.
when the receiver is triggering it is only should prompt a toast, nothing happened, except that the number on the dialer is getting cleared after the last *. it seems the dialer didn't broadcast the intent to trigger the receiver

Comment: @Elior any updates on this issue? Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @AntonKizema Hi, no.. on some devices this method will not work.
it looks the dialer is not catching the intent that was sent from the receiver.